# Is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to ask this question, let me know if this is on topic or not. Else you can suggest me some different SE (non SE) site where I can probably get answer.

What is happening at molecular level when we say "Person is showing attitude". By attitude I mean general  expression of favor or disfavor toward a person, place, thing, or event (as given in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_%28psychology%29) and I agree with that definition). Most of literature is on Psychology but I am interested in signalling pathways.

I am guessing this can be posted on Cognitive Science SE but I am interested more towards molecular signalling than neurological explanation.

Comment: I would assume the underlying molecular mechanisms would be similar. Just the circuits would be different. This would be on-topic if you present the background clearly.

Comment: on-topic, yes, but answerable - no. It's like explaining the workings of a rain forest or coral reef at the atomic scale.

Comment: @AliceD, I agree it's broad but at least someone can give outline. E.g. atoms --> Molecules --> Cells --> Tissue --> Organisms --> Group of organisms --> Rain forest (or coral reef).

Comment: It's not going to happen. I considered close voting it because it's too broad/unclear but I value your efforts in the question too much to do that :)

Comment: That's not fair. I knew some moderator will raise this issue, hence I posted first on meta site. Looks like even that case I was wrong. You can delete question if you want :/

Comment: Not fair? That I didn't close vote? O.o

Answer (score 2):

I would find this to be very broad question as there can be so many different pathways and signaling for it to be described in one question. However, if the question was more narrowed down then it could be better. This is more narrowed down, but still may be too broad - "What is the molecular reason for showing attitude?". Another example could be "what parts of the brain are active when a person is 'showing attitude'?

Cognitive Sciences.SE also would definitely be a better place to post this. There are some useful tsgs there, like "neurobiology", "cognitive-modelling", "cognitive-neuroscience", and more.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but unfortunately, I have already deleted question.